# How add new font to android activity

Tags: android, textview, android-fonts

I developed an android application now i'm trying to add (Kulturista Bold. ttf )this custom font to it but it doesn't worked Here is my login.xml file and login.java files

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/maintitle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="CREATE AN ACCOUNT?"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                   android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
                android:gravity="center"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CLICK ON THE SIGHNUP AND REGISTER"
            android:textColor="#c4cbcf"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
             />
```

This is the activity code

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.maintitle);  
        Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Kulturista_Bold. ttf");  
        txt1.setTypeface(font1);  
        TextView txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subtitle);  
        Typeface font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Kulturista_Bold. ttf");  
        txt2.setTypeface(font2);
    }

}
```

Comment: are u same a your typeface like this your assets folder like this `Kulturista_Bold. ttf` once check the name may use this `Kulturista_Bold.ttf`

Comment: Where is your `ttf` file? in asset folder ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access from only assets folder then in your code just remove space from ***. ttf***

So change it

```
Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Kulturista_Bold.ttf");
```

If you have created folder named fonts in assets folder then you have to access it by.

```
Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Kulturista_Bold.ttf");
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove space from ". ttf"

```
//Space between dot(.) and ttf Kulturista_Bold. ttf
Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Kulturista_Bold. ttf");
```

Try this by removing space.

```
Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Kulturista_Bold.ttf");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `getContext` or `activityName` before `getAssets`:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext(),"fonts/androidnation.ttf");
```

or

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(activityname.this.getAssets(), "fonts/androidnation.ttf");

txt1.setTypeface(font);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Kulturista_Bold.ttf");
txt2.setTypeface(typeFace);
```